# Reshaping with None in tensorflow or keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reshape

Suppose I have a tensor of shape `[None, 80, 80]`. This is a batch of 80x80 images for stochastic gradient descent.

Suppose I choose the minibatch size as 50, (None will be 50), and I want to factor the None into two dimensions `(5, 10)`, resulting in `[?, ?, 80, 80]`.

How do I achieve this when forming the graph with None value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with [`tf.reshape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 80, 80], name='x')
y = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 10, 80, 80], name='y')
data = np.zeros([50, 80, 80])
with tf.Session() as session:
  result = session.run(y, feed_dict={x: data})
  print result.shape
```

Result output:

```
(5, 10, 80, 80)
```

Of course, keep in mind that passing an unsuitable batch size will result in exception at runtime.